# How to save output of a function in a variable without overwriting when it gets called multiple times? Tktiner Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, overwrite

With the following Code I manly want to get selections from listboxes.
When a Button is pressed the function will be called. If I do a debug print from selection_listboxes. When  push the button, I get different debug prints with different value lists,  of the things I chose. But when I try to get the variable selection_listboxes in a other part of the programm it's always the same values in the list. **How can I save the selections of the listboxes in variables, when the function gets called multiple times, with out overwriting it all the time?**

```
 def get_selection_l(self, window, button_lib, list_elements, listbox):
        **self.selection_listboxes** = [list_elements[int(item)] for item in listbox.curselection()]
        if self.is_unmarked == TRUE and self.selection_listboxes:
            try:
                self.confirm_Button_comp.config(state='disabled')
            except TclError:
                pass
        if not self.selection_listboxes:
            self.selection_listboxes = ""
        button_lib.config(state='normal')
        print(self.selection_listboxes)
        window.destroy()
```

Comment: Did you check there's no other function overwriting the variable?

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439786/13629335